# AngularJS: .addEventListener() on window.open()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth

In my AngularJS-App, I want to open a new Popup and attach an EventListener on it. Here is the according part taken from angular-oauth1-client:

```
 var auth_window = window.open(authorizeEndpoint + "?oauth_token=" + oauth_token + "&oauth_callback=" + callback_url, '_blank', 'location=yes,clearcache=yes,hidden=yes');
        auth_window.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
            console.log('hi');
            if((event.url).startsWith(callback_url)) {
                if(angular.isFunction(beforeWindowClose)){
                    beforeWindowClose();
                }
                auth_window.close();

                deffered.resolve({
                    returned_oauth_token: getURLParameter(event.url, 'oauth_token'),
                    oauth_verifier: getURLParameter(event.url, 'verifier'),
                    wp_scope: getURLParameter(event.url, 'wp_scope')
                });
            }
        });
```

The desired window opens, but it looks like the EventListener isn't working because I don't get a console.log when I do a reload.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Maybe the event is already complete before you attach event listener.

Comment: That was my first guess. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: I am not sure about what is event related to, browser window? You can try to attach to a event that happens later. Or `auth_window.onload(function() {});`

Comment: event should be an object containing the new windows property, yes :)